# Unable to access Splunk via port number on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, ubuntu-12.04, splunk

Ubuntu 12.04 Server x64 &
Splunk 6.0

I installed Splunk according to the documentation. Started Splunk as directed and I am able to see it running in the terminal. I believe I correctly added the default port number - 8000 - to iptables with the following command:

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT

However, I am still unable to access it. It just continuously attempts to connect (white screen in browser) when I type in my domain name or public IP address followed by the IP address. I checked the Splunk logs and it is showing a standard startup without issues. I restarted and tried a few other quick fixes but so far nothing. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Leave it to outside influences. The client is hosting on Amazon EC2 and by default, all ports are blocked at the network level. You have to open the port up through AWS console. This is solved.

Comment: what is the result for "netstat -an | grep 8000" from your server ?

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Comment: Did you try to check if you have incoming packets on port 8000 on server side using tcpdump ?